# Help to delete music

Tags: itunes, itunes-store

Can I delete music off my phone without this deleting my music on my iTunes account? If I can then will the songs reappear once I plug my phone back into my mac

I need space on my phone but don't want to loose it completely or for it too reappear when I sync it.

Comment: Will they reappear once I plug my phone back into my mac?

Answer (score 1):

You could delete a song in the iTunes app on your device just by swyping from right to left over the song name. There will be an option to delete the song.